# error while deploying next.js app on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

```
window.console.error = function() {
 for (var e = arguments.length, t = Array(e), r = 0; r < e; r++)
                t[r] = arguments[r];
            (0,
            p.isNextRouterError)(t[0]) || y.apply(window.console, t)***//it shows error in this line***
        }
        ,
        window.addEventListener("error", e=>{
            if ((0,
            p.isNextRouterError)(e.error)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return
            }
```

[image]

I checked for any visible error in my code it's all good and no error on vercel side also

Comment: Getting the exact same error using app router. Were you able to resolve it?